# cpan / perl messed up

Tags: perl, cpan

Lubuntu Xenial. I seem to have messed up my system perl. 
cpan returns:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/cpan: no such file or directory
```

(I built a newer perl version from source in that directory, but removed it again).

```
apt-get install perl --reinstall
```

seemed to do the right thing but didn't solve the problem.
I don't dare to purge perl first and reinstall it, as apt might depend on it.

What can I do?

Comment: "*I built a newer perl version from source in that directory*": what directory? Surely you didn't build in `/usr/local/bin`, right? Also Is it perl that's screwed up or cpan? What happens if you run `perl -v` or something? What does `type -a cpan` return? Does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure perl` help?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Are you sure you don't have something left over from your perl-new-version-play?   I have cpan located in /usr/bin/cpan, and nothing related to perl in /usr/local/bin/ (the only stuff in /usr/local/bin/ is stuff I put there)

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR: Running `hash -r` or just starting a new shell usually fixes this problem.*

#### If the file is actually gone, then the shell probably just still has it hashed.

First I suggest you verify that `/usr/local/bin/cpan` really is gone:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/cpan
```

If there is something there, then you didn't fully uninstall. If there is nothing there, then you will get this message:

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/cpan': No such file or directory
```

Assuming you got that message, but `bash` is trying to run `/usr/local/bin/cpan` when you type in `cpan` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the problem is most likely that **`bash` still has that path [hashed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-hash)**. Rather than looking up where external commands are every time, shells typically hash their locations. So you can fix the problem by [telling `bash` to "rehash,"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267900/11938) by running:

```
hash -r
```

Or just start a new shell.

#### If that doesn't work, check if it's an alias or shell function.

If the file is neither still present nor still hashed, then most likely `cpan` is an alias or shell function that acts as a wrapper for `/usr/local/bin/cpan`. To ascertain this, run:

```
type -a cpan
```

If it's an alias or shell function, that will show the definition. Then you can unset it with `unalias cpan` if it's an alias, or `unset -f cpan` if it's a shell function.

You will ultimately want to remove the definition from whatever startup script contains it. Usually it will be in the `.bashrc` file in your home directory. Aliases are sometimes defined in `.bash_aliases`. (Occasionally people define aliases and shell functions in `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bash_login`, even though this is not a very good practice.)

#### If that doesn't work, consider how you're running `cpan` or what shell you're in.

*If the file is gone, not still hashed, not an alias or shell function, and `type -a` doesn't reveal the problem*, then most likely you are either (a) not running `cpan` directly through that command, or (b) using a shell other than `bash`.  In the former case there is no way to answer without further details.

The latter case seems unlikely since your shell *calls itself* `bash`, though every once in a while someone ill-advisedly makes a symlink called `bash` to a shell that isn't (which isn't advisable). The truth is, I'm mainly mentioning this for the benefit of other readers. Based on that message, you're almost certainly using `bash`.

However, in case you're not or might not be, run `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to see if you're running `bash`--this should be unset in other shells--and `echo "$SHELL"` to see what your *default* shell is. Rehashing works differently--or is at least *achieved* differently--in other shells.

Some other Bourne-style shells, [like `zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html#l30), have a `rehash` command that you would run instead of `hash -r`. That is also how you would cause rehashing  to occur [in `csh` and `tcsh`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mj6/index.html).

Comment: Still a problem remaining. While running cpan I get these errors:#   Failed test 'failed x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE  -o ccode10 ccode10.c  -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt 2>/dev/null'
# 
#   at t/TestBC.pm line 934.
# 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# 256

Comment: This one I solved with [apt-get install libperl-dev --reinstall]

Comment: @KrisVanBruwaene It sounds like your solution may be different enough to be a separate answer. I can't really tell for sure--in particular, error messages are hard to understand when they are scrunched into comments with spacing and line breaks not shown. But I encourage you to considering [posting your own answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). The system will even allow you to *immediately* mark your own answer as the accepted answer, because more than two days have passed [since you *originally* posted the question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).